# Find "/" in first character from an array of URLs and remove "/"

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have an output result:

```
array(['ubersicht/dashboardtest',
   '/transfermarkt/2016/09/transfers-spielerwechsel-bundesliga-international | galerie',
   'ubersicht/live', ..., 'fussball/wm-quali',
   'uebersicht basketball', 'fussball/uefa-nations-league-d'],
  dtype=object)
```

I want to go through each Url and remove `/` present only at `position[0]` of every url present in `array`.

E.g:

`ubersicht/dashboardtest` ----- `/` not present so `u` should not be removed

`/transfermarkt/2016/09/transfers-spielerwechsel-bundesliga-international | galerie`  ---- `/` is present and hence should be removed.

I will be grateful if it is solved.

Regards

I have tried url parsing, but its not url exactly , i have 2000+ urls without domain name in excel sheet.

Comment: `str.lstrip(r"/")` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use list comprehensions and the string built in method `lstrip()`. Suppose you have your array named `x`, you can do

```
>>> [str(xx).lstrip(r'/') for xx in x]
```

This gives

```
['ubersicht/dashboardtest',
 'transfermarkt/2016/09/transfers-spielerwechsel-bundesliga-international | galerie',
 'ubersicht/live',
 'Ellipsis',
 'fussball/wm-quali',
 'uebersicht basketball',
 'fussball/uefa-nations-league-d']
```

Comment: Thats is perfect solution ! for xx and x 

i have saved the array in urls so it will be xx in this case?

Comment: Glad, if it works out for you. I forgot to mention, that I supposed your array is named `x`. I edited my answer accordingly. Your saved urls would be in array `x`. You could save it to some other variable by e.g. `y = [str(xx).lstrip(r'/') for xx in x]` or simply overwrite `x` itself